# Use any Protocol in array

Tags: swift, swift-data

I would like to store an array of "Protocol" type in my SwiftData model. There are several different classes that conform to the `ItineraryItem` protocol. However, I always get the error `Type 'any ItineraryItem' cannot conform to 'PersistentModel'` when building the project.

[image]

**Code**

```
@Model
final class Trip: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var items: [any ItineraryItem] = []
    
    init(name: String, startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
    }
}
```

```
protocol ItineraryItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var type: ItineraryItemType { get set }
    var startDate: Date { get set }
    var endDate: Date { get set }
    var notes: String? { get set }
}
```

Comment: Short answer, you don't store and array of Protocol or even a single object of Protocol, you store an array or a a single object of a concrete type (class, struct, enum).

Comment: Post formatted code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: @DuncanC the screenshot with the error is from the `@Model` macro expansion, copy+pasting the macro expansion into the question doesn't add too much value.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that Swift sees the array and assumes there's a relationship there. And relationships can only be made with other models, which your protocol is not. That's what the error message tells you.

However, if your goal is to have "simple" (i.e. non-model) type conforming to `ItineraryItem`, then what prevents you to achieve the goal is the fact that an array of `any Codable` is not `Codable`, as the compiler can't decode from data to `any Codable` as it doesn't know which type to decode. The `Encodable` protocol doesn't preserve type information, so if you want to decode an encoded value, then you need to use a concrete type for this operation.

A workaround to this would be to use an enum that wraps over your concrete types, this will give enough type information to the compiler:

```swift
enum ItineraryItemWrapper: Codable {
    case someItem(SomeItineraryItem)
    case anotherItem(AnotherItireraryItem)

    var itineraryItem: any ItineraryItem {
        switch self {
        case let someItem(item): return item
        case let anotherItem(item): return item
        }
    }
}
```

, and then declare the property as an array over the enum:

```
var items: [ItineraryItemWrapper] = []
```

The downside is that the enum doesn't scale well, as every new `ItineraryItem` conformer will need a new enum case.

Comment: Many thanks, that's an interesting thought. However, the enum makes it a bit clunky to use. Would you go with inheriting from a base model class instead?

Comment: @gpichler it depends if `ItineraryItem` makes sense as a `Model` or not